# How would remote postischemic conditioning be implemented as first aid?

Tags: first-aid, myocardial-infarction

Remote postischemic conditioning (or ischemic postconditioning) has been widely discussed for years.  A [review from 2014](https://www.karger.com/Article/FullText/362499#ref47) described promising results from a test of the procedure with a blood pressure cuff in an ambulance.  From the literature, it seems like there *might* be some simple procedure, such as using a cuff or tourniquet to block circulation to a limb for a few 15-30 second intervals, that could be done to or perhaps even *by* a person suffering a heart attack immediately after the onset of symptoms.

Question is ... where would such direction come from, and is there any process in place by which it has been or will be considered?